# random and pointers doesn't work

Tags: c, pointers

Hello I'm trying to increase float to Pointer But somehow The program prints all the time 0.00000.
The number should be drawn between 12.01 to  -13.00.

My code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    float* num = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float));

    srand(time(NULL));

    *num = rand() % 1300 + 1201 / 100.00;

    printf("%f",num);
    system("PAUSE");

    free(num);
}
```

I would love if someone could help me fix it thanks.

Comment: In the printf, are you printing a number or a reference to one?

Comment: Why are you allocating memory for a single variable? Why not use simple `float num = rand() ...`? This will incidentally solve your problem.

Comment: No you're *not* printing the number.

Comment: I allocating memory Because I check a few things ...

Comment: So what should I do to print the number?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg is right, you don't need to manually allocate memory for this (and it's probably better if you don't; in general, the less pointer usage you have, the better off you are). Just declare a regular `float` variable and work with it.

Comment: `*num = (rand() % 100 + 1201) / 100.00;`

Answer (score 4):

note the * if you want to print the number while you're printing the address :

```
printf("%f",*num);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to print the value that num points to:

```
printf("%f", *num);
```

Comment: Thanks my mistake I did not notice

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. Don't cast your `malloc` in C (unrelated to your problem but [a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/2088135) nonetheless)
2. Enable compiler warnings

Doing both of these things will help you avoid problems. Compiling with `gcc -Wall` I get:

> warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'float *' [-Wformat=]
>      printf("%f",num);

which would have answered your question. You are using a `%f` format specifier but passing a pointer, not a `float` or `double`. You need to dereference your pointer:

```
printf("%f", *num);
```

Answer (score 1):

These are errors:

- `*num = rand() % 1300 + 1201 / 100.00;`

  `*num` is in the [12.01, 1311.01] range. If you need a number in the [12.01, 13.00] range, change the assignment:

  ```
  *num = 12.01 + (rand() % 100) / 100.0;
  ```
- `printf("%f", num);` should be `printf("%f", *num);`

Also it's a good idea to enable extra warnings during compilation. E.g. with `-Wall -Wextra`

```
clang -Wall -Wextra filename.c
warning: format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type 'float *' [-Wformat]
```

Same with gcc

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra filename.c

warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'float *' [-Wformat=]
```

If you are playing with `malloc`/`free` you should check for allocation failures.

Memory allocation is not guaranteed to succeed, and may instead return a null pointer. If there's no check for successful allocation implemented, this usually leads to a crash of the program, due to the resulting segmentation fault on the null pointer dereference.

So you could change your code in this way:

```
float *num = malloc(sizeof(float));
if (num)
{
  // your code
}
else
{
  // handle failure
}
```

Anyway it's better to just use a simple float.

Answer (score 1):

In addition of fixing `printf("%f", *num);`, you need to check your math!

If you really want result between 12.01 and -13.00,

```
*num = (rand() % 2501 - 1300) / 100.00;
```

Answer (score 0):

You program invokes undefined behaviour because `num` is not a `float` but a pointer to a  `float` and your trying to print it as a `float` by `%f` conversion specifier in `printf` call. Also, don't cast the result of `malloc` and explicitly mention `void` in the paramater list of `main`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    float *num = malloc(sizeof *num);
    srand(time(NULL));
    *num = rand() % 1300 + 1201 / 100.00;
    printf("%f", *num);   // note *num instead of num
    system("PAUSE");

    free(num);
}
```